# When I play a WAV in python, the program doesn't stop when the file ends, leaving the program unresponsive

Tags: python, audio, wav, pyaudio

So we were tasked with writing a short program that play a song for the user, and then ask them to guess the genre of the song, after which the program asks if they want to hear another song or if it wants to quit.
The problem I am having is when the program first plays the song. It first prints out the title of the quiz, and asks the user if they want to hear a song, or exit the quiz by inputting "-1". However, if the user chooses to play a song, it plays the song, but doesn't continue to the next part of the quiz (guessing the genre)once the clip ends. The program just stays in this "play" mode and I can't do anything, bar entering cntrl+C.

I have searched around relentlessly for an answer to this problem, I have wrote out simpler programs just to see if it will ever continue past playing the song, even asking my lecturer about the problem (he didn't have any answers for me strangely).
Here is my code (playWav2 is the pyaudio script for playing a wav file):

```
import playWav2 as pw
#Here I am providing the list of genres and songs for the program to take info from. 
#I am using "s" for the song list, and "i" for the genre list.
genre_list=['melodic punk','alt rock','drum and bass','house','punk rock']
song_list=["Welcome to Paradise.wav","Worry Rock.wav","Propane Nightmares.wav","Lalula.wav","Life During Wartime.wav"]
i=0
s=0
#Here I am providing the participant with the ability to play a song
decision=input("Guess the genre of the song! (enter any key to play a song. Enter -1 to finish the quiz)")
if decision == '-1':
            exit()
else:
    pw.play(song_list[s])        


#Here I am showing the participant the list of possible genres to choose from.
print("heres a list of my favorite genres!")
print(genre_list) 
#Here the participant guesses the genre     
genre=input("What genre do you think that was?")
#If the genre is correct, it plays the next song, if it is not in genre_list, it stops.    
while genre == genre_list[i]:
    print("Great guess! %s is correct!"%(genre))
    choice=input("Ok, so now that you got that right, ready to try another? (y/n)")
    if choice.lower() == 'y':
        i+=1
        i%=5
        pw.play(song_list[s])
    else:
        break
```

Here is the code to playWav2:

```
""" Play a WAVE file. """

import pyaudio
import wave

chunk = 1024

def play(song):
    wf = wave.open(song, 'rb')
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    # open stream
    stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels = wf.getnchannels(),
                rate = wf.getframerate(),
                output = True)

    # read data
    data = wf.readframes(chunk)

    # play stream
    while data != '':
        stream.write(data)
        data = wf.readframes(chunk)
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
```

Comment: What's the minimal script which doesn't work? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Searching for [playWav2](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=playWav2+python) comes up with three links, one being this question

Comment: Hey! This is the simple script I made to see if it would continue past playing the WAV.                                                                                             `import playWav2 as pw

pw.play("Welcome to Paradise.wav")  
print("did it work?")`

Answer (score 4):

Yes the code above never leaves the loop. A bit late, but try to exit it when `b''` (an empty string of bytes) is returned. This works for me. (I had to change `wf` by `sound`).

```
sound = wave.open("your.wav")
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
chunk = 1024
stream = p.open(format =
                p.get_format_from_width(sound.getsampwidth()),
                channels = sound.getnchannels(),
                rate = sound.getframerate(),
                output = True)
data = sound.readframes(chunk)
while True:
    if data != '':
        stream.write(data)
        data = sound.readframes(chunk)

    if data == b'':
        break
```

Comment: just tried simple while check as below and it worked for me. Ububtu 20.04, anaconda with jupyter, pyaudio 0.2.11    while data != b'': stream.write(data)  data = wf.readframes(chunk)

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the above code, but in your module playWav2

As you list pyaudio as a reference, take a look at [The example on the pyaudio page](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/), specially how the example ends..

Or provide the code for playWav2.

Comment: playWav2 code:                                                

``import pyaudio
import wave

chunk = 1024

def play(song):
    wf = wave.open(song, 'rb')
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

   
    stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels = wf.getnchannels(),
                rate = wf.getframerate(),
                output = True)

    
    data = wf.readframes(chunk)

    while data != '':
        stream.write(data)
        data = wf.readframes(chunk)
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()``

Comment: As you probably already know, correct indenting is crucial to python. You need to update your question if the comment won't allow you to insert code with the proper formatting.

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely new to this site. How do I go about getting proper formatting in my comments?

Comment: @AaronK5521 Edit your question instead of trying to have a conversation about code.

Comment: Good! I see this is essentially the pyaudio example. It runs fine on one of my systems (Windows7, Python2.7.11, pyaudio0.2.9). I used a wav file from the Windows installation for test. So what we don't know is your system setup and we don't have your files either. I assume you have tried with other files?

Comment: Yes I have used other sample wav files, all resulting in the same situation. The only difference I can think of is that I am using python 3.5, and I run my program in command prompt.

Comment: Okay, I get the same result as you when running in Python 3.5.1. Adding a couple of printouts makes it clear that execution never leaves the while loop. Try changing it to   while len(data) > 0:           Your lecturer should be asking "why does that work?" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    data = wav_file.readframes(chunk)
    if not data:
        break
    stream.write(data)  # to be played
```

Comment: The bug is in this loop, and fixed here.  As described on this page and many others across the net.

Comment: Edit it into the answer please.